# dual boot windows 10 sleep dont work properly

Tags: dual-boot

I've been having problems with the sleep mode in windows 10 using dual boot with ubuntu 18.04. When I put windows on sleep mode and then reactivate it, it appears like I have restart the pc, that show me the grub menu and when i select the windows boot manager, nothing of what i've been doing still there. ITS A COMPLETELY HEADACHE.
I tried to change the boot flag with gparted but still not working.
What can i do?

Comment: have you tried [`boot-repair`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863) yet?  You should probably disable hibernation and "fast startup" on Windows if you haven't already done this

Comment: didn't work :(.